# Did Frau Blucher think the monster was the original one?

Tags: plot-explanation, young-frankenstein

In "Young Frankenstein", Frederick von Frankenstein (Fron-ken-steen, mind you) moves into his grandfather's castle and continues the work of his infamous relative (Victor von Frankenstein from the Mary Shelley novel). He finds a new body, surgically inserts a new brain, and brings his creation to life using the same method as the original. Because his assistant Igor (Eye-gor, grandson of the original) grabbed the wrong brain, the monster is violent and aggressive.

The housekeeper, Frau Blucher (*horse whinnies*) - who loved Victor - sets the monster loose, stating that he is gentle as a lamb and loves violin music. Oddly enough, playing the violin does indeed seem to calm the monster.

**Why did Frau Blucher (*horse whinnies*) think that this new monster was the old one (or did she), and why did music calm both monsters?**

Comment: Plus one for the horse whinnies, but I don't think she believed the monster was the same as the original.

Comment: @Tim - fair enough, I could be wrong about her motivation there. I tweaked the question a little to include that.

Comment: "What knockers!"

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, she was the one who led Frederick to Victor's work and believed in the genius of the Frankenstein family.  She set the second monster free because she trusted so thoroughly in Victor's belief that the monster was inherently good.

The violin thing...  I think that comes from the old saying, "Music soothes the savage beast".  It's been used in several contexts, from old Bugs Bunny cartoons to the Magician sequence in Disney's Fantasia.